# Use Ansible install OpenShift : Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.199.27.30, 172.30.0.1, not 127.0.0.1

Tags: openshift-origin

Description
CentOS 7.4
openshift 3.10
one master,two compute nodes,one infra-node

## ansible-playbook ~/openshift-ansible/playbooks/prerequisites.yml -vvv `is ok`

Use Ansible install ：

## ansible-playbook ~/openshift-ansible/playbooks/deploy_cluster.yml -vvv

error result：

```
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for APIs to become available (47 retries left).Result was: {
"attempts": 14,
"changed": true,
"cmd": [
"oc",
"get",
"--raw",
"/apis/apps.openshift.io/v1"
],
"delta": "0:00:00.212621",
"end": "2018-09-30 11:38:56.650360",
"invocation": {
"module_args": {
"_raw_params": "oc get --raw /apis/apps.openshift.io/v1",
"_uses_shell": false,
"argv": null,
"chdir": null,
"creates": null,
"executable": null,
"removes": null,
"stdin": null,
"warn": true
}
},
"msg": "non-zero return code",
"rc": 1,
"retries": 61,
"start": "2018-09-30 11:38:56.437739",
"stderr": "Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.199.27.30, 172.30.0.1, not 127.0.0.1",
"stderr_lines": [
**"Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.199.27.30, 172.30.0.1, not 127.0.0.1"**
],
"stdout": "",
"stdout_lines": []
}
^C [ERROR]: User interrupted execution
```

and use shell command：

```
[root@master ~]# oc get pod
```

**Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.199.27.30, 172.30.0.1, not 127.0.0.1**

```
Version
[root@master openshift-ansible]# ansible --version
ansible 2.6.4

[root@master openshift-ansible]# git describe

openshift-ansible-3.10.51-1-16-g1a911c5

[root@master ~]# cat /etc/ansible/hosts

# Create an OSEv3 group that contains the masters, nodes, and etcd groups

[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes
etcd

# Set variables common for all OSEv3 hosts
[OSEv3:vars]
# SSH user, this user should allow ssh based auth without requiring a password
ansible_ssh_user=root

# If ansible_ssh_user is not root, ansible_become must be set to true
#ansible_become=true

openshift_deployment_type=origin

# uncomment the following to enable htpasswd authentication; defaults to AllowAllPasswordIdentityProvider
#openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider'}]
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider'}]
openshift_master_htpasswd_users={'admin':'$apr1$CGxDnhjD$Mif/EZWaIhRPAmxXWba6O0'}

#openshift_release=3.10

openshift_disable_check=memory_availability,docker_image_availability,package_availability,package_version

# host group for masters
[masters]
master.ctwifi.cn

# host group for etcd
[etcd]
master.ctwifi.cn

# host group for nodes, includes region info
[nodes]
master.ctwifi.cn openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master'
node01.ctwifi.cn openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'
node02.ctwifi.cn openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'
infra-node1.ctwifi.cn openshift_node_group_name='node-config-infra
```

Please help me! thank you so much!